# Using QSqlQueryModel in another thread and access it directly by pointer from main thread?

Tags: multithreading, qt

I've used a subclass of QSqlQueryModel to expose the data for a ListView in my QML project. I want to do both of these in the same time:

1. Expose the model to QML using `setContextProperty()` with the **model's pointer**.
2. Leave the model in another thread so when I call the model `update()` function (executing the last query to reflect the data changed in database), the model won't block the UI when it's requerying the database.

Is it possible? If not, what is the better solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution is: Subclass `QThread`, pass the `QmlApplicationViewer` pointer to its contructor and inside the new class `DatabaseQueryThread`, I set the context property for the viewer there. This way, Qt will allow me to provide access to the query model directly by pointer.

Comment: I'd like to see other answers to this problem. What I had in mind was: the model in a separate thread shared with the UI thread so that when the model is blocking, the UI will wait for it to finish. For example, calling `select()` on a `QSqlTableModel` with 900k rows takes 30s on my MBP in which the UI freezes waiting for the model to return from `select()`. The UI could instead wait for a thread to signal `ready()` then `setModel()` on the `QTableView` passing it a pointer to the model, if it's safe and possible to share the model between threads.